# Discord Bot Studio

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Using Discord Bot Studio v2.1.1 command flow, how would I add Guild creation date into my send embed command flow? Also my guild owner name var + region name var always says undefined

I've tried to store the variable, and then send the embedded message calling the variable under my variables

Comment: Please post your code.  We can't read your mind.

Comment: [link](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/917919464786386944/1131406031516352553/image.png) Here's my command nodes

[link](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/917919464786386944/1131405932644024411/image.png) Here's my embed 

[link](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/917919464786386944/1131406907169579089/image.png) Here's my stored value

[link](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/917919464786386944/1131405155166859354/image.png) And here's my result

Would adding anything into my commands or variables .json ensure a fix?

Comment: If it was a typo it should be closed as that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found a fix to this, just had to do a bit of browsing for anyone else wondering the same thing, my issue was I had a typo in the ${tempVars.guild.createdAt} variable when I should have used ${dbsVars.guild.createdAt}